# Sending XML http requests in java

Tags: java, xml, apache, http, xmlhttprequest

Does anyone know what I can use instead of StringRequestEntity() as it has been deprecated?

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("my endpoint url bla bla bla");
post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
String xmlRequest = new String(sw_reg.toString());
log.info("Setting request body to  [" + xmlRequest + "]");

//Send the request
post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xmlRequest));
httpclient.executeMethod(post);
```

Comment: I've downvoted because asking the question does not really show research effort. The deprecated constructors Javadoc points to the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation (found [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/StringRequestEntity.html)), you should use the following constructor instead

```
public StringRequestEntity(String content,
                           String contentType,
                           String charset)
                    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
```

> Creates a new entity with the given content, content type, and
> charset.

So you just need to add the content type and charset as extra parameters to the constructor call.  Parameter description below...

> **content** - The content to set.
>
> **contentType** - The type of the content,
> or null. The value retured by getContentType(). If this content type
> contains a charset and the charset parameter is null, the content's
> type charset will be used.
>
> **charset** - The charset of the content, or
> null. Used to convert the content to bytes. If the content type does
> not contain a charset and charset is not null, then the charset will
> be appended to the content type.